# using wildcards in vimrc abbreviations

Tags: vim

I'm setting up my `.vimrc` for writing some HTML and currently have these lines:

```
abb <buffer> <h1> <h1></h1><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
abb <buffer> <h2> <h2></h2><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
abb <buffer> <h3> <h3></h3><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
abb <buffer> <h4> <h4></h4><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
abb <buffer> <h5> <h5></h5><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
abb <buffer> <h6> <h6></h6><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
```

Which automatically adds a closing tag to any opening h-tag I write, moves the cursor to the middle of them and gets rid of the whitespace with the function from `:helpgrep Eatchar`

My qestion is, if there is a more elgant way of doing this, by telling vim to take take <h[1-6]> and adding a closing tag with the same number, instead of having to define each case specifically?
Or for that matter, is there a way to define this whole process of adding a closing tag and moving the cursor back as a function and then just specifying all the tags I want it to be applied to? Because below this I have a quite a few lines for a bunch of other tags that look almost identical.

Comment: Why don't you use a snippet expansion plugin?

Comment: @romainl I try to avoid using plugins if possible, so far I've been able to do everything I need with just vanilla vim

Comment: Copying functions and commands and mappings found in `:help` or in SO answers is *not* "just vanilla Vim".

Comment: @romainl Then I guess pluginles vim is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a function to satisfy my similar requirement recently. This feature can be found in other tools like VSCode.

When I type `>`, it'll try to look back to check if `>` is in a tag like `<div>`. If so, it will complete it and set cursor at `<div>|</div>`.

Compared with emmet or snippets, this way feels more straightforward.

```
function! CompleteTag()
  let line = getline('.')
  let end = col('.') - 1
  let begin = end - 1
  let tagname_regexp = '[a-zA-Z0-9-]'

  while begin > 0
    if line[begin] !~ tagname_regexp
      break
    endif
    let begin -= 1
  endwhile

  if line[begin] == '<'
    let tagname = line[begin+1:end-1]
    let move = MoveBack(len(tagname)+3)
    return '></'.tagname.'>'.move
  endif

  return '>'
endfunction

function! MoveBack(n)
  let move = ''
  for i in range(0, a:n-1)
    let move .= "\<Left>"
  endfor
  return move
endfunction

autocmd FileType jsx,html,vue,svelte inoremap<buffer> > <c-r>=CompleteTag()<cr>
autocmd FileType jsx,html,vue,svelte inoremap<buffer> <c-cr> <cr><esc>O
```

Comment: nice, I like it. I think I'm going to expand on this and add a list of tags for which it should add a newline between the tags (like section). Need to get a little more into vimscipt before I can do that though

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Please note I slightly modified the code by using local mapping (`inoremap<buffer>`) as well as a cleaner style for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `:help abbreviations` nor `:help mapping` can use a wildcard on the left hand side. One solution to that kind of problem is to loop over heading levels and create your abbreviations programatically:

```
for level in range(1, 6)
    execute "abbreviate <buffer> <h" .. level .. "> <h" .. level .. "></h" .. level .. "><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\\m\\s\\<bar>/')<CR>"
endfor
```

It certainly is a tad more clever but I wonder if the loss of legibility is really worth it.

Comment: I find that it's a bit more readable if the string is built with a single `printf()` but that might just be a matter of preference: `execute printf("abbreviate <buffer> <h%d> <h%d></h%d><ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\\m\\s\\<bar>/')<CR>", level, level, level)`

Comment: Preferences indeed, I'm not a fan of `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to parameterize a single abbreviation; I suspect you'll need to delve into functions for that. You can, however, define a map consisting of the trailing part:

```
inoremap nowsp <ESC>?<<CR>i<C-R>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>/')<CR>
```

then use that map in your abbreviations

```
abb <buffer> <h1> <h1></h1>nowsp
abb <buffer> <h2> <h2></h2>nowsp
" etc
```